# Writing an script interpreter in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, netbsd

I wrote a bash wrapper to ruby that goes through various setup steps.

The most basic version is,

```
   #!/bin/bash 
   #   ruby_wrapper.sh
   ruby
```

Now I want to be able to use this wrapper just like regular ruby! Specifically, I want to create a .rb file that uses this "interpreter".

```
   #!/path/to/ruby_wrapper.sh
   #  my_file.rb
   puts "hello world"
```

So I want to be able to do `$ ./my_file.rb` instead of `$ ruby_wrapper.sh my_file.rb`

Is this possible?

The [documentation](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?script+7+NetBSD-current) claims it isn't.

> Note that the interpreter may not itself be an interpreter script.

But I don't see why not. Does anyone have any ideas to get around this?

Comment: The documentation you link and quote from is for NetBSD, not Linux.

Comment: True but the same is true on linux. http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html
>The interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable which is not itself a script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try invoking your wrapper with `/usr/bin/env`. It's actually good practice to execute Ruby scripts with `/usr/bin/env ruby` as you don't have to hard code the path to the `ruby` binary, so this is not unnatural.

```
$ cat ruby_wrapper.sh 
#!/bin/bash
exec ruby "$@"

$ cat wrapped.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env /tmp/ruby_wrapper.sh
puts "hello world"

$ ./wrapped.rb 
hello world
```

Also as a side note see how I've used `exec` in the wrapper script. This will allow the ruby interpreter to take over your wrapper script's process rather than run as a child process of your script. This makes the wrapper transparent to the caller (signals will be delivered directly to ruby rather than to bash, for example).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I read about the /usr/bin/env trick being used for portability, but didn't realize it would bypass this restriction.